# Global Chart implies no cut locus?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

If a manifold $M$ admits a global chart, does this imply that there exists a point $p\in M$ such that $Cut_p=\emptyset$?

---

**Recall: Definition of $Cut_p$:**

Let $\mathfrak{C}_p$ be defined as the set of all vectors v in $T_pM$ such that $\gamma(t)=\exp_p(tv)$ is a minimizing geodesic for each $t \in [0,1] $ but fails to be a unique minimizing for $t \in [0,1 + \epsilon)$ for each $\epsilon > 0$ *(Note: uniqueness is important because on $S^1$ the cut-locus is the antipodal point).*

We define $Cut_p:=Exp_p(\mathfrak{C}_p)$ and call this the cut locus of $p$ in $M$.

Comment: What does $Cut_p$ denote in this instance?

Comment: I edited the post and added the definition of $Cut_p$ into it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My inution, which I don't know how to make precise, is that if you start with flat $\mathbb{R}^2$ and add a few mountain shaped bumps in a random locations, you probably end up with every point having a nonempty cut locus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider capital alphabet $T$. Intuitively consider a surface $S$
bearing $T$ It is like a union of disk and cylinder

$C_1$ is homeomorphic to a disk with boundary $B_1$ and $C_2$ is
homeomorphic to a cylinder whose boundary $B_2,\ B_3$ And $$\partial
S=B_3,\ S=C_1\cup_{B_1=B_2} C_2,\ B_i\approx S^1 $$

If we attach $S$ into punctured plane $P$ along $S^1$ so $$
S_2:=S\cup_{B_3} P $$

Then any point in $S_2$ can tie $C_2$ which can not be shrink